# Liquibase doesn't execute SQLs and returns Update Successful

Tags: sql, postgresql, liquibase

I have created a new PostgreSQL DB on my PC,

```
  CREATE DATABASE "Test_Liquibase_Versionin"
  WITH OWNER = postgres
       ENCODING = 'UTF8'
       TABLESPACE = pg_default
       LC_COLLATE = 'English_United States.1252'
       LC_CTYPE = 'English_United States.1252'
       CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
```

Downloaded liquibase-3.4.2-bin and run this command:

```
C:\LiquiBase\liquibase.bat --driver=org.postgresql.Driver --classpath="C:\LiquiBase\Driver\postgresql-9.4.1212.jar" --changeLogFile=C:\LiquiBase\changes\databaseChangeLog.sql --url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Test_Liquibase_Versionin?user=test&password=Password" update
```

Got this response `Liquibase Update Successful`

check the DB and notice that I have 2 tables `databasechangelog, databasechangeloglock`

changed databaseChangeLog.sql to look like this:

```
--liquibase formatted sql


create table employees( uuid int, name Varchar(10));
insert into employees values(1, 'Mr');
insert into employees values(2, 'Mail');
create table depts( dept_id int, dep_name Varchar(10));
```

executed again `C:\LiquiBase\liquibase.bat.........`

Got this response `Liquibase Update Successful`

Logged into my DB - but there are no new tables as expected.
What could be the reason for that? What could I do to test whats gone wrong?

Comment: Is there anything in `databasechangelog`?

Comment: no, it is empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a changeset to the script.

This is because you are telling Liquibase that your sql script is `Liquibase formatted sql`. But since you do not have any changeset in it, it does nothing.

```
--liquibase formatted sql

--changeSet PeterH:Inserting-Values1 endDelimiter:; splitStatements:true stripComments:false runOnChange:false

create table employees( uuid int, name Varchar(10));
insert into employees values(1, 'Mr');
insert into employees values(2, 'Mail');
create table depts( dept_id int, dep_name Varchar(10));
```

Comment: I suspected something like that, but as I only use the XML format I wasn't sure.

Comment: Can't remember which endDelimiter should be used for postgresql, someone will help me out here

Comment: `;` should be fine I guess

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was setting liquibase header on the file, but the problem was with an space between username (the user that makes the change) and the parameter:

```
--liquibase formatted sql
--changeset Jenkins: scriptname.sql stripComments:true splitStatements:true
```

As you can see, there is an space between "Jenkins:" and "scriptname.sql". I've deleted that space and it runs ok

Comment: My issue was something similar to this. thanks